# ethernet not working after reboot on Ubuntu Server 20.04.2

Tags: networking, ethernet

I had an ethernet connection successfully working, but now after a reboot it's no longer working.

`sudo lshw -C network` reveals

```
*-network ... 
  description: Ethernet interface ...
  ... 
  product: RTL8111 ...
  ... 
  logical name: enp4s0
```

`cat /etc/network/interfaces` is empty

`ip link show` reveals

```
  2: enp4s0:  ​... state DOWN mode DEFAULT
    ... link/ether
```

after `sudo ip link set enp4s0 up`
, then `ip link show` reveals

```
2: enp4s0:  ​... state UP mode DEFAULT
     ... link/ether
```

but still, `ping 192.168.0.1` results in `ping: connect: Network is unreachable`

`/etc/netplan` has a file called `00-installer-config.yaml` with contents

```
network:
  ethernets:
    enp3s0:
      dhcp4: true
  version: 2
```

N.B. I don't currently have `ifconfig` or `net-tools` installed

What should I try to get my ethernet connection working again?

Comment: I would like to just comment on the above but I don't have the karma - this solution didn't work for me because ```netplan``` isn't installed on my instance (20.04.3 - server). Any other ideas?

Answer (score 7):

Realized shortly after asking:

change `enp3s0` to `enp4s0` in `/etc/netplan/00-installer-config.yaml` and then run `sudo netplan apply`, and ethernet is working again

Comment: Adding more information for future reading users: since version 18.04, Ubuntu does not support `ifconfig` and overall any utils provided by `net-tools` such as `netstat`. Instead, we now have an improved verstion of `ip` commands included in newly added `iproute2` package, as well as newly added `netplan` as you already discovered. About newly added `ip` commands and `net-tools` [alternatives](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iproute2). About `netplan`: see Canonical's official `netplan` dedicated website: [netplan.io](https://netplan.io).

Comment: I ran into an error like this. On some reboots the netplan just assigns completely random enpX names to NICs that don't exist. I can't emphasize how much I hate the new netplan/network manager post Ubuntu 18.X.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: check your  /etc/netplan/00-installer-config.yaml
My yaml config was not formatted correctly for nics eno2 to eno4.

Please forgive my long answer. Here is the scenario: Ubuntu 20.04.1 fresh install. Platform = HP Proliant with a Intel I350 4-port nic.

Problem: after a sudo apt update and sudo apt upgrade - I have 20.04.5 and Linux 5.4.0-137-generic on x86_64. There are many posts on this issue - upon reboot, no networking. Keep in mind the I was/am working via ssh so prior to the reboot, networking was good.

> lshw -C network | more     gave me DISABLED.
> ip link show                       DOWN

I did a > cat /etc/netplan/00-installer-config.yaml
The file existed and the info was correct.

sudo netplan apply    gave me an indent error.

> sudo nano /etc/netplan/00-installer-config.yaml
> I corrected the indent issue for each nic port eno2 - eno4
> Save.

sudo netplan apply and the network started right up.