# Intermittent network issues on server 22.04.1 after reboot

Tags: networking, server, internet

I had another network issue on Ubuntu Server here: [Ethernet is disabled after reboot - Ubuntu server 20.04.3](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1383206/ethernet-is-disabled-after-reboot-ubuntu-server-20-04-3). This one was "solved" by wiping and reinstalling from scratch.

But this time it appears to be a different issue - after a restart my Ubuntu Server machine (v22.04.01) would not connect to the internet (100% packet loss when pinging google.com, 1.1.1.1, 8.8.8.8). I had no issues connecting via ssh or samba.

What was interesting was when I run `mtr 8.8.8.8` (or other addresses) it would start getting packets back after several minutes, and then the connection would cut out again after several more.

This has persisted through several reboots. I've tried `sudo netplan generate` and `sudo netplan apply` (followed by another reboot).

When I run `ping google.com` it resolves the IP address (142.250.72.78), which I assumed meant there isn't a DNS issue. However, if I change my router settings from dynamic DNS to static DNS to either 1.1.1.1 or 8.8.8.8, the internet connection comes back immediately - and then drops out several minutes (or longer) later.

No other router changes have been made, and all other devices, wired and wireless, on my network are working flawlessly. This machine has been running Ubuntu Server 22.04.01 for several weeks without issue, which makes this very perplexing to me that it suddenly stopped working.

## Update 11/28/2022

This appears to be caused by Plex Media Server. As soon as I install and enable plexmediaserver according to the instructions here: https://support.plex.tv/articles/200288586-installation/ I get the internet connectivity problems described above.

Disabling the firewall altogether does not fix the issue, which I found surprising.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discovered the issue - after a modem update (Century Link CX4000G) the "Cyber Security" mode in the modem Advanced Settings was blocking all traffic whenever Plex was active.

Disabling that mode fixed the connectivity issues.

Unfortunately CL's documentation of this "Cyber Security" program is virtually non-existent - I'll be in contact with them to see if disabling it is actually safe.